# Proper way of handling linked data in statistical context

Tags: python, statistics

I have a couple of data points from an experimental setup. The experiment was conducted several hundred times. For each experiment, 5 data points at defined moments in time (`t_1` - `t_5`) were measured.

In [this sketch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lNisE.png)  the mean values and the standard deviation for these measurements is shown.

I got these results by mainly performing:

```
import numpy as np
datas = [data0, data1, data2, data3, data4]
datasMean=[]
datasStd=[]
for data in datas:
    datasMean.append(data.mean())
    datasStd.append(data.std())
```

Using some statistical analysis, I want to get insights regarding my assumption that at time `t_4` really the measured value is lower than at the other times - in relationship to the other data points in that experiment.

Is there any approach to show that this assumption is right? My fear is that my experimental results could e.g. mainly consist of 40 percent green data points and 40 percent blue data points (or some other more complex distributions that are even more smeared) as shown [in this sketch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RThAa.png).

How can validate my assumption, that in a significant amount of experimental runs, really the data point for `t_4` is always lower **in relationship** to the other data points **for a certain experiment**?

Which functions of `numpy` or `scipy.stats` (or other packages) would be suitable to solve this question?

Comment: This question is about research design/statistics and not programming.

Comment: Yes, in general you are right. I just updated the question a little bit to indicate the relationship for a proper function of `scipy.stats` or a similar packages. I hope this helps.

Comment: most likely you need to model the data using a linear model or a model that is appropriate for the distribution of your data. You then test the effect of t4 versus all others

Comment: without data, and with those sketches.. its very vague at the moment and i don't see any programming part in this. vote to migrate this to cross-validated

Answer (score 0):

Does this capture a section of how your data looks like?:

```
Experiment   t1 t2 t3 t4 t5                
experiment1  a  b  c  d  e
experiment2  a  b  c  d  e
experiment3  a  b  c  d  e
experiment4  a  b  c  d  e
experiment5  a  b  c  d  e
```

Where a,b,c,d and e are data points recorded at defined times t1-t5. And you would like to verify your assumption that for a certain experiment,d is always lower than a,b,c and e?

Here is working solution:
An adjustment to how a section the data looks.

```
Experiment  t1  t2 t3 t4 t5               
experiment1  2  10  4  8  1
experiment2  3   3  2  5  2
experiment3  9   2  7  6  3
experiment4  4   1  6  4  5
experiment5  6  20  3  5  7
```

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#change column dtype to numeric
df[['t1', 't2','t3', 't4','t5']] = df[['t1', 't2','t3', 't4','t5']].apply(pd.to_numeric)

# new column holding minimum value occurring in every row
df['min_value'] = df.idxmin(axis=1)
```

result:

```
Experiment  t1  t2  t3  t4  t5  min_value                   
experiment1 2   10  4   8   1   t1
experiment2 3   3   2   5   2   t3
experiment3 9   2   7   6   3   t2
experiment4 4   1   6   4   5   t2
experiment5 6   20  3   5   7   t3
```

Comment: well, the `a` for experiment1 will be different from the `a` of experiment2. Therefore a notation to distinguish them (like `a_1`, `b_1`, `c_1`, `d_1`, `e_1` for the first row - and accordingly for the following rows, too) will probably make sense.

Comment: One way to verify is to obtain the  minimum value (row-wise) of each experiment. I edited the answer above to show how this can be done.